# preg_replace not replacing with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, regex

I have the following code

```
$text = '["{!Account__!http://localhost/MF/Public/__NotActivated}","email"]';

$replcmnt = array(
    '#{!Account__!http:\/\/localhost\/MF/Public\/__NotActivated}#' => 'text to replace'
);

$text = preg_replace(array_keys($replcmnt),$replcmnt,$text);
```

I need the output to be `'["text to replace","email"]'` but for some reason the replace isn't replacing. I find this extremely weird as this works when I load the page but doesn't work if I run it via ajax request O.o

I also have to note that if I remove any slashes from the inner part between the underscores the replace takes place. So the problem must be something with those slashes.

ex.

```
$replcmnt = array(
    '#{!Account__!http:-localhost-MF-Public-__NotActivated}#' => 'text to replace'
);
```

The above will get replaced due to the lack of slashes, I suppose.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT**:

Here's the data right before the replace:

```
$text
["{!Account__!http:\/\/localhost\/MF\/Public\/__NotActivated}","email"]

$replcmnt
Array
(
    [#{!Account__!http:\/\/localhost\/MF\/Public\/__NotActivated}#] => some long text
)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the unnecessary backslashes in the regexp?

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace` rather than `str_replace`? There are no regular expression characters in your pattern.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised it's not reporting an error, because `{}` are special in regular expressions.

Comment: @barmar because this is a universal algorithm, but I'm having trouble with this particular case. As to curly brackets, I know, me too. But it even surprises me more that it works just well when I'm loading the page and not working when I'm sending it as ajax, it's the same script I just can't wrap my head around what might be causing this O.O

Comment: doubt it's the slashes. since you're using `#` as the pattern delimiter, the slashes aren't anything special in the rest of the pattern.

Comment: I just tried your original code, it works as desired for me.

Comment: It does work with me as well with an ordinary request, but doesn't with ajax O.O

Comment: You said that it works except when being used via AJAX. That suggests that the problem is with the way you're sending the text parameter.

Comment: Are some of those characters being URL-encoded or something when being sent via ajax?

Comment: I updated the question with the data printed right before the replace in the ajax request

Comment: @Barmar I converted to `str_replace` as you suggested and the problem is no more. Answer that if you like so I can accept it as solved :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` rather than `preg_replace()`, since you're not doing any pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not working with JSON as a string but rather working with the actual data structure it represents. You could deserialize the JSON and just replace the array element like this:

```
$test_array = json_decode($text);
$test_array[0] = $text_to_replace;
$new_json = json_encode($test_array);
```

Comment: That's great but my problem isn't about how I'm structuring my stuff

Comment: @php_nub_qq I didn't say it was. My suggestion does nothing to change your data structure, but would produce your desired results. You are trying to replace one array element in a JSON string with another. You can just do this in an actual array rather than having to resort to regex functionality. You are just taking a serialized data input and deserializing it, changing the data, and serializing it again for output.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Actually in looking at the input JSON more closely, it is not valid JSON, so I am not sure if you would be able to decode it properly.

Comment: I can't decode this because this is a single case. It may be so that the string I need to replace isn't json at all or it may be mixed, that's why I'm working with strings instead of json objects. And it is valid json array object